# Problem initializing OneSignal in android App - Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, init, onesignal

Description:

When initializing OneSignal on app clients side, I get:

Unknown error getting FCM Token
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Please set your project ID. A valid Firebase project ID is required to communicate with Firebase server APIs: It identifies your project with Google.

My dependencies:
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.2' //OneSignal didn´t work when this was activated
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.2.4' //for FCM

Crashing curently

Answer (score 1):

Solved...

Just had to follow the UPDATED guideline on OneSignal Documentation (SDK setup)...they had changed a few things if I am not wrong.